# How can i make this INSERT in PL/SQL Procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

I am new in pl/sql programming and I need your help.

I would like to make a procedure.

To be more specific, I have tables like the folowing TABLE1

```
================================================
|COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |COL7|
===============================================
|600 | 140 | 2 | 10 | 1300 | 500 | 1 |
|600 | 140 | 2 | 20 | 1400 | 340 | 4 |
|600 | 140 | 2 | 15 | 1400 | 230 | 3 |
|600 | 140 | 2 | 35 | 1700 | 120 | 2 |
|600 | 150 | 3 | 10 | 1300 | 166 | 6 |
|600 | 150 | 3 | 15 | 1400 | 435 | 5 |
----------------------------------------------
```

For the same COL1 and COL2/COL3 , check the select different values from COL4
For instance for COL1=600 , COL2=140/COL3=2 and COL2=150/COL3=3
Return 20 and 35

And insert in this table TABLE1 the rows

```
600 , 150 , 3, 20 , 1400 , 340, 7 (seq number)
600 , 150 , 3, 35 , 1700 , 120, 8 (seq number)
```

I make inserts in Table1 if P_FLG1 = 'Y'. IF P_FLG2 = 'Y' I make inserts also in TABLE3 etc

I am trying to make the procedure like below but I can't finish it

```
PROCEDURE COPY_COLUMNS  ( P_COL1        IN  A.COL1%TYPE,
                          P_FROM_COL2   IN  B.COL2%TYPE,
                          P_FROM_COL3   IN  B.COL3%TYPE,
                          P_TO_COL2     IN  B.COL2%TYPE,
                          P_TO_COL3     IN  B.COL3%TYPE,
                          P_FLG1        IN  VARCHAR2,
                          P_FLG2        IN  VARCHAR2,
                          P_FLG3        IN  VARCHAR2                                      
                                     ) IS


CURSOR CFL1 IS select COL4
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
    MINUS
    select COL4
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3;

CURSOR CFL2 IS select COL4
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
    MINUS
    select COL4
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3;

CURSOR CFL3 IS select COL4
    FROM TABLE3
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3
    MINUS
    select COL4
    FROM TABLE3
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_TO_COL2 AND COL3 = P_TO_COL3;  


V_REC        CFL1%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

IF P_FLG1='N' OR P_FLG2='N' OR P_FLG3='N' OR  P_FLG4 ='N' OR P_FLG5 = 'N' THEN
    GOTO label; --do nothing
END IF;


IF P_FLG1 = 'Y' THEN

    OPEN CFL1;
    FETCH CFL1 INTO V_REC;
    CLOSE C1;

    SELECT COL5, COL6
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 = P_COL1 AND COL2 = P_FROM_COL2 AND COL3 = P_FROM_COL3 AND COL4 = V_REC.COL4;


    FOR REC IN CFL1 LOOP
        INSERT INTO TABLE1 
            SELECT P_COL1, P_TO_COL2, P_TO_COL3, CFL1.COL4, -- COL5 , COL6 ?? -- , SEQ.NEXTVAL) 

    END LOOP;

END IF;

-- ..........

<<label>>
END;
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFL1.COL4 won't work, since you need to reference the resultset variable : REC.COL4.

And it doesn't hurt to specify the columns of the table you insert into.
for example :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col1, col2) values (rec.col1, rec.col2);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (col1, col2) select rec.col1, rec.col2 from dual;
```

Also, you first fetch the CFL1, expecting only 1 record value. 
But then use the same cursor in loop. Remove the fetch and get that col4 value from REC? A direct select in a procedure won't work anyway.